# What is the purpose of flash keys in stm32 or in another microcontroller?

Tags: memory, key, stm32, flash-memory, unlock

Why do you have to write a key which is given in the reference manual to unlock the flash memory. What kind of security is this?

Answer (score 2):

If no keys any accidental sector or mass erase would erase the FLASH. Key + command sequence is much less probable and (I use STM32 for many years) it never happened to me.

Comment: Quite common also in critical peripherals like watchdogs that can be disabled, just to avoid destructive bugs.

Comment: How you can erase flash memory accidentally by writing a bit to a register if it is not directed in your program. If it is directed in your program you will see it erase flash memory in your tests.

Comment: @Yedin if the world was fair then your assumption is OK. But I afraid it is not.